# Show commits for branch on remote

Tags: git, tig

With `git log --graph` I get to see commits pushed to remote origin after I did a `git pull` last:

[image: git log]

in `tig` I don't see these commits:

[image: tig]

Is there some flag or config I'm missing to get to see this in tig?

Comment: Try --all with tig. Its showing you only local branches and not remote branches. That means --all option is not set!

Comment: `--all` was great! Also I found the `r` key and could see all the references in ref view. But `--all` seems to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that it worked! :) M adding the comment as answer, I guess an accepted answer will be more helpful to others than comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `--all` with tig.

Running it without `--all` displays only local branches. To see the remote branches as well you have to use the `--all` option.